# What is the tightest bound for a given converge series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I currently consider the following question.

Given a converging series
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\frac{x_i}{i^{\alpha}})^2 < \infty \ \textit{for} \ \alpha>0
$$
what is the tightest upper bound for each $x_i$?

My current idea is assume $x_i \asymp i^{-\beta}$. Then it leads to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^{-2(\alpha+\beta)} < \infty.
$$
By the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^{-a}<\infty$ for $a>1$, we obtain $\beta>\frac{1}{2}-\alpha$ and therefore a possible upper bound for $x_i$ is $i^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}$.

But my question is whether it is possible to prove this is the tightest bound for $x_i$, if not, is there any possible method to get the tightest bound?

Comment: $\alpha$ is serving two purposes in this.  First it is used in the sum of interest, then it is used in the statement that the series must go to zero faster than $i^{-1}$.  One can sort it out, but it would be easier on the reader if one set is changed to another variable.

Comment: As stated there is no bound on individual $x_i$ only as their behavior as $i\to \infty$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't bound any given $x_i$ by the fact that the sum converges.  Given any sum that converges, the same sum with any individual $x_i$ changed to something large like $10^6$ still converges.  Making the change only makes a finite change to the sum, so it cannot change the convergence.

Leaving that aside, we have the fact that $\sum_i^\infty \frac 1{i \log i}$ diverges and $\sum_i^\infty \frac 1{i (\log i)^2}$ converges, which gives a lower upper bound.  I didn't specify where the sum starts because early terms cannot change convergence as in the first paragraph.  We can go further.  We know $\sum_i^\infty \frac 1{i \log i \log \log i}$ diverges and $\sum_i^\infty \frac 1{i \log i (\log \log i)^2}$ converges.  You can continue the chain as far as you want until you get tired or bored.